# KeyedHashAlgorithm in .net core

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I need to convert the following .Net code to .Net Core:

```
static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
{
    String algorithm = "HmacSHA256";
    KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
    kha.Key = key;

    return kha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}
```

The above snippet is used for Amazon AWS key signing and is taken from [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet).

I'm using System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives 4.3.0 and KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create method doesn't exists. Looking at the [github](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/9d42f078b13a8f8a437914094699ab80bfd1fd42/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives/src/System/Security/Cryptography/KeyedHashAlgorithm.cs) I can see that the Create method is there now, but it's not supported:

```
 public static new KeyedHashAlgorithm Create(string algName)
        {
            throw new PlatformNotSupportedException();
}
```

The question is what is my alternative to KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(string algName) in .Net Core?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .Net Core seems to be providing [HMACSHA256 Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256) which should be exactly what you need:

```
static byte[] HmacSHA256(String data, byte[] key)
{
    HMACSHA256 hashAlgorithm = new HMACSHA256(key);

    return hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this would work, just word `new` is missing from the code: `new HMACSHA256(key);`

Comment: @Ross Right - fixed it ;)

Comment: Don't forget to throw it in a using block

Answer (score 1):

FYI, you can save yourself the trouble of generating the key signature manually if you use the AWSSDK.

```
using Amazon.Runtime.Internal.Auth;

DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

string signature = ToHex(AWS4Signer.ComposeSigningKey("yourSecretKey", "us-west-2", now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), "s3"));

public static string ToHex(byte[] data)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Here is how I did using suggested AWS4Signer:
`private string _Signature(string stringToSign)
    {
        byte[] key = AWS4Signer.ComposeSigningKey(AppSettings.AmazonS3.SecretAccessKey, AppSettings.AmazonS3.Region, Datestamp, AppSettings.AmazonS3.Service);
        return (AWS4Signer.ComputeKeyedHash(SigningAlgorithm.HmacSHA256, key, stringToSign).Hex());       
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = KeyedHashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm);
```

with

```
KeyedHashAlgorithm kha = (KeyedHashAlgorithm)CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(algorithm);
```